# How can I pass pre generated array to component in template in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, components

I have an items array and loop it into a component. Display items props separately:

**Items Array**

```
const items = [
    {
        'name': 'item1', 
        'prop1': 'text1', 
        'prop2': 'text2',
        'boolval': true
    },
    {
        'name': 'item2', 
        'prop1': 'text1', 
        'prop2': 'text2',
        'boolval': false
    },
    {
        'name': 'item3', 
        'prop1': 'text1', 
        'prop2': 'text2',
        'boolval': true
    }];
```

**Component**

```
<div class="all-items">
    <app-items [item]="items"></app-items>
</div>

<div class="specific-items">
    <app-items [item]="items"></app-items>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="title">List</div>
<p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>
<p>Prop1: {{item.prop1}}</p>
<p>Prop2: {{item.prop2}}</p>
```

I want to display all items under the **.all-items** div, but display item which has **boolval=true** prop under the **.specific-items** div. Generated HTML for all-items looks like the following:

```
<div class="all-items">
    <app-items>
        <div class="title">List</div>
        <p>Name: item1</p>
        <p>Prop1: text1</p>
        <p>Prop2: text2</p>
    </app-items>
    <app-items>
        <div class="title">List</div>
        <p>Name: item2</p>
        <p>Prop1: text1</p>
        <p>Prop2: text2</p>
    </app-items>
    <app-items>
        <div class="title">List</div>
        <p>Name: item3</p>
        <p>Prop1: text1</p>
        <p>Prop2: text2</p>
    </app-items>
</div>
```

I want to display specific items like this;

```
<div class="specific-items">
    <app-items [item]="items.filter(x => x.boolval=== true)"></app-items>
</div>

<div class="specific-items">
    <app-items>
        <div class="title">List</div>
        <p>Name: item1</p>
        <p>Prop1: text1</p>
        <p>Prop2: text2</p>

        <p>Name: item3</p>
        <p>Prop1: text1</p>
        <p>Prop2: text2</p>
    </app-items>
</div>
```

How can I generate a specific array in template like this **[item]="items.filter(x => x.boolval=== true)"** and pass it to component? So I want generate a specific array in template and then send it to component

Comment: What are you expecting `.map(x => x.bool === true)` to do? This will return a **new array of booleans** You probably wanted **.filter** instead (you should use a `Pipe` for that though https://angular.io/guide/pipes) . That said, you should either use a component getter, either generate the array first, it's not a great practice to bind a function (or a getter) to an angular component if it performs heavy operations (like array mapping).

Comment: sorry I misspelled, I've corrected map as filter

Comment: Could you have a typo in `x.bool`? Your array items have a field called `boolval`.

Comment: you're right, I've corrected, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pipe to filter the array.

Here is [the final solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyqt7y?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

`app-items.pipe.ts`

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'appItemsFilter'
})
export class AppItemsFilter implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items) {
    return items.filter(x => x.boolval);
  }
}
```

And you can simply use it as following

```
<div class="all-items">
  <app-items [items]="items"></app-items>
</div>

<div class="specific-items">
  <app-items [items]="items | appItemsFilter"></app-items>
</div>
```

Also, this pipe is pure which means angular will not call `tranform` method unless `items` array reference change (operations like `push`, `pop` won't trigger change detection) So, performance will be a lot better than calling methods from template.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, you can try below-

```
    <div class="all-items">
    <app-items *ngFor="let item of items;let i= index">
        <div class="title">List</div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.boolval">
        <p>Name: {{item?.name}}</p>
        <p>Prop1: {{item?.prop1}}</p>
        <p>Prop2: {{item?.prop2}}</p>
      </ng-container>
    </app-items>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added the code in [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqumkj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

modified the HTML structure little and added some conditions.

```
<div class="all-items">
    <app-items [items]="items" case="1"></app-items>
</div>

<div class="specific-items">
    <app-items [items]="items" case="2"></app-items>
</div>

<div class="title">List</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngIf="case == 1 || (case == 2 && item.boolval == true)">
        <p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>
        <p>Prop1: {{item.prop1}}</p>
        <p>Prop2: {{item.prop2}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass pipe direclty to the array to *ngFor

```
@Pipe({
 name: 'itemsFilter'
})
export class AppItemsFilter implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items) {
   return items.filter(x => x.boolval);
  }
}
```

in your html

```
  <div class="specific-items">
  <app-items>
   <div class="title">List</div>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items | itemsFilter">
      <p>Name: {{item?.name}}</p>
      <p>Prop1: {{item?.prop1}}</p>
      <p>Prop2: {{item?.prop2}}</p>
    <ng-container>
  </app-items>
</div>
```